# Flexbox item shrinking more than its child content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make two columns of items expand/shrink in a bigger column to fill the available space.
Now when I fill 1 of the child divs with items, the other one shrinks below the its items height, making it only like 50% visible, like this:
[Light green is the actual item, dark green is the div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8DHu.png)

I've tried using flex-shrink: 0, but once I fill the top div with items, it stretches and overflows without the scroll beyond the boundaries of parent div.

I've also tried setting min-height, but if I have no items in the top div, the bottom div wont stretch all the way to the top.

Min-height: -webkit-min-content works the same as setting fixed min-height, no scrollbar when i overfill the parent div.

```
<div class="container no-padding" style="display: flex; align-content: flex-start; flex-direction: column; max-height: 50%">
    <div class="list-group mx-auto no-padding " style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-grow: 1; width: 100%; overflow-y:auto">
        <div class="no-padding" style="flex-shrink: 0">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="channel-name">Meow</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group mx-auto no-padding " id="channel-list" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-grow: 1; width: 100%; overflow-y:auto">
        <div class="no-padding" style="flex-shrink: 0">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="channel-object" name="channel">channel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `ml-auto` for the second div. and remove `mx-auto` for first div.

Comment: How would that help? mx-auto is there only to center the divs horizontally in the master column